# How to print a list with no leading commas with sep=", " into a string?

Tags: python, list, printing

The title maybe a bit confusing so here is the gist of it:

I have this list:

```
mylist = [0, 4, 8, 12]
```

and I want to print only the elements after some string.

So I did this:

```
print("The arithmetic sequence is:", *mylist, sep=", ")
```

The outcome that I want is

> The arithmetic sequence is: 0, 4, 8, 12

However what I got is this:

> The arithmetic sequence is:, 0, 4, 8, 12

Notice the extra comma in between the 0 and the colon

I'm guessing that `sep=", "` is the culprit, but I don't know how to get rid of the leading comma

Comment: `print("The arithmetic sequence is: " + ", ".join(map(str, mylist)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `sep=` is that the string is inserted between all parameters, including between `"The arithmetic sequence is:"` and the first value in `myList`. Use a f-string and `str.join` instead. You'll have to convert the values to strings as you go

```
>>> mylist = [0, 4, 8, 12]
>>> print(f"The arithmetic sequence is: {', '.join(str(v) for v in mylist)}")
The arithmetic sequence is: 0, 4, 8, 12
```

Answer (score -2):

```
mylist = [0, 4, 8, 12]
print("The arithmetic sequence is:", ', '.join(str(i) for i in mylist))
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.